# Search using jquery is not working fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to search text using jquery.

When I try to search for the word "Joe", The first Header  " Name / Surname" should not be displayed because the first header belongs to people "Vatanay Özbeyli, Burak Özkan, Egemen Özbeyli, Bozuyük

It should display  only

Name / Surname
Joe

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".search").keyup(function() {
    var searchTerm = $(".search").val();
    //var listItemHead = $('.results thead').children('tr');
    //var listItem = $('.results tbody').children('tr');
    var searchSplit = searchTerm.replace(/ /g, "'):containsi('")

    $.extend($.expr[':'], {
      'containsi': function(elem, i, match, array) {
        return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '').toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
      }
    });

    $(".results tbody tr").not(":containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e) {
      $(this).attr('visible', 'false');
      $(".results thead tr").attr('visible', 'false');
    });



    $(".results tbody tr:containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e) {
      // if($(this).find(".results tbody tr:containsi('" + searchSplit + "')")) {
      //   $(".results thead tr").attr('visible','true');
      // } else {
      //   $(".results thead tr").attr('visible','false');
      // }
      $(this).attr('visible', 'true');
      //alert($(this).parent());
      $(".results thead tr").attr('visible', 'true');
    });

    var jobCount = $('.results tbody tr[visible="true"]').length;
    $('.counter').text(jobCount + ' item');

    if (jobCount == '0') {
      $('.no-result').show();
    } else {
      $('.no-result').hide();
    }
  });


  $(function() {
    var mark = function() {
      // Read the keyword
      var keyword = $("input[name='keyword']").val();

      // Determine selected options
      var options = {};
      $("input[name='opt[]']").each(function() {
        options[$(this).val()] = $(this).is(":checked");
      });

      // Remove previous marked elements and mark
      // the new keyword inside the context
      $(".context").unmark({
        done: function() {
          $(".context tbody tr").mark(keyword, options);
        }
      });
    };

    $("input[name='keyword']").on("input", mark);
    $("input[type='checkbox']").on("change", mark);

  });

});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px 20px;
}

.results tr[visible='false'],
.no-result {
  display: none;
}

.results tr[visible='true'] {
  display: table-row;
}

.counter {
  padding: 8px;
  color: #ccc;
}

mark {
  background-color: rgb(238, 130, 238);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/mark.js/8.6.0/jquery.mark.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="search form-control" name="keyword" placeholder="What you looking for?">
  </div>
  <span class="counter center-block"></span>

  <div class="alert alert-warning no-result"><i class="fa fa-warning"></i> No result</div>


  <table class="table table-hover results context">
    <thead>
      <tr class='heading'>
        <th class="col-md-5 col-xs-5">Name / Surname</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Vatanay Özbeyli</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Burak Özkan</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Egemen Özbeyli</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bozuyük</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table table-hover results context">
    <thead>
      <tr class="heading">
        <th class="col-md-5 col-xs-5">Name / Surname</th>
      </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Joe</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Tim wood</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ryan Martin</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Richard Gin</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

[Jquery search issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7BDS.png)

Comment: All you need to do is find the snippet of code where you are hiding things after getting the search results, and make it hide more things. Are you able to pinpoint where the hiding happens?

Comment: `$(".results thead tr").attr('visible', 'true');` looks like you select all thead elements, not the one for the current table

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery datatable

CSS

https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css

JS

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.results ').DataTable();
} );
```